# Fixing permissions on Android SDK directory

Tags: android, sdk, permissions

I have just transitioned from one Ubuntu machine to another.  I didn't want to have to redownload the Android SDK all over again, so I copied my `~/android-sdks` directory from the old machine to the new.  I believe the permissions may have gotten messed up during the copy, e.g. `platform-tools/abd` wasn't copied across as executable.  I think this is giving me more grief in Eclipse now (c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/a/886494) because other files don't have the permissions they need to do what they need to do.  Is there an easy way to fix the permissions on the `~/android-sdks` directory without redownloading it again/manually trying to find which files need permission changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into a similar problem installing the sdk on a new Mac. I'm guessing the solution is similar.

Being a long time java developer, I often use the java "jar" utility to manage zip files. I di the following...

```
$ java xf ~/Downloads/adt-bundle-max-x86_64-20130522.zip
```

... all the files were extracted properly, but the execute bits were not set. I blew the directory away and re-extracted with unzip...

```
$ rm -rf adt-bundle-max-x86_64-20130522
$ unzip ~/Downloads/adt-bundle-max-x86_64-20130522.zip
```

... now the execute bits were preserved.

Comment: I haven't tested this myself, but if ziping the directory and then using `unzip` to extract the files retains the executable permissions, then that seems like a solution to me.  So I've marked this the accepted answer.